# Cross browser testing tool with camera and mic access

Tags: web-browser, automation

We need to perform cross browser testing for a web conferencing platform (like Google Meet, Zoom etc). However, I couldn't find any tool that supports both camera and mic devices in browser.

BrowserStack support team told this feature is out of their roadmap at the moment, SauceLabs doesn't have camera access as well. Though both supports mic, camera access is essential for us. Other similar projects I've checked doesn't seem to have cam access too.

**Could you recommend cross browser testing tool with both camera and mic access?** That's ok if camera would output just black screen, main requirement - the device should be accessible.